# Terminal broadcast output to input of another terminal

Tags: terminal

Trying to find a way to broadcast the *output* of one terminal over to the input of another terminal.  I am using iTerm2 on Mac, but it could be any other terminal utility.

I know of the broadcast input in iTerm, but that is not what I want to do. I could just copy the output of one term and paste into another, but I want to find a way to accomplish this for a long running session.

Comment: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261531/how-to-send-output-from-one-terminal-to-another-without-making-any-new-pipe-or-f) might be what you're looking for

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for!  I'll post the iTerm2 specific answer below.